# Py4JError in installing pyspark 3.0.3

Tags: python

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#creating a sparksession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

When running this code, I get the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MPTy.png).

I don't understand why this is showing an error. can anyone help out, please?

The version is 3.0.3

I tried running the above code for a spark session on google colab. it's been difficult going past the error. the spark version I am using is 3.0.3. i have done `pip install`.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.